# Cocoa dot syntax of a dot syntax

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is it ok to use syntax like this:

```
Object.parent.property
```

or should I restrict it to one dot and one level only?

Comment: look up 'law of demeter': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Comment: The wikipedia page was very helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it is okay to use:

```
a.b.c
```

However, if there are structures involved then it might not work. Consider the following class declaration:

```
@interface Circle : NSObject
@property (assign) NSPoint centre;
@end
```

In this case, the `centre` property is of type `NSPoint`, a structure (not a class!) that declares two members, `x` and `y`. Reading the `x` coordinate works:

```
CGFloat x = circle.centre.x;
```

and is equivalent to:

```
CGFloat x = [circle center].x;
```

but writing the `x` coordinate doesn’t:

```
circle.centre.x = 50;
```

because the left part of the assignment, called an lvalue, is not assignable. The assignment is trying to change a member variable of a return value, namely the structure returned by `[circle centre]`.

You’ll have to to write this instead:

```
NSPoint centre = circle.centre;
centre.x = 50;
circle.centre = centre;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is perfectly fine and common to use syntax like that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is ok, it does not matter how many levels. They all get translated to this.

```
[[[[Object parent] property] anotherProperty] yetAnotherProperty]
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
Object.parent.property.anotherProperty.yetAnotherProperty;
```

This explains it all: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17